# Working with Bootstrap and unable to get a styles.css to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to get a simple bootstrap example working.  I'm now getting desperate in order to get a simple css override to work.  I have one line commented out that works if I use it but when I use my css file, nothing works.  I went as far as to use the actual website location which is not what I want but this doesn't even operate.  I'm baffled about this behavior.

I'm actually just trying to put an background image on the jumbotron but I have to get my script to at least read a css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>A broken test example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.virtualalchemy.org/Styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1>Test Example</h1>
<!--          <p style="padding-top:125px">Example</p> -->
                        <p>Example</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Get Started</a>
                    </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Typo? `hrel` instead of `href`

Comment: seems as typo....link should have href

Answer (score 1):

Line 6 looks like it has a typo. The [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) should have a `href` rather than a `hrel`.

Apart from that, I see no reason why this should not work. Are you aware that your external stylesheet only has one rule in it?

Comment: I don't know why my example had hrel but my webpage uses href, that's why I formatted both lines to insure I didn't create any typos.

Comment: Have you ordered the stylesheets correctly? Custom styles should always come after vendor styles, like your above example. Also, are there any errors in the browser console when your site is loaded?

Comment: The page is identical to the example.  Simple, clean and I don't understand why it will not work.  I even made the href as a webpage link so the file could be viewed from any web brower.

Comment: Try lowercase changing your href link and physical filename to lowercase and/or using HTTPS?

Comment: I've tried different cases already.  I had a css folder and I even moved the file under the same directory that the html file is located.  I'm going to move it to my hard drive and switch to file:/// to see if that will at least get it working for a demo for my client.  I haven't touched html in over 10 years and I thought bootstrap would be a simple way to get a website up and running.

Comment: To get this working, I've had to just simply resort to using:

    <head>
    ...
    <style>
    .jumbotron {
    background-image: url("image.jpeg");
    }
    </style>
    </head>